# How to get the variable value from xml array

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

```
$ebs_status_response_xml = new SimpleXMLElement($result);
print_r($ebs_status_response_xml);
```

Then response is below.

```
SimpleXMLElement Object (
                       [@attributes] => Array 
                                ( [transactionId] => 55113838 
                                  [paymentId] => 22239729 
                                  [amount] => 499 
                                  [dateTime] => 2014-01-09 13:03:18 
                                  [mode] => LIVE 
                                  [referenceNo] => 100014102  
                                  [transactionType] => Authorized 
                                  [status] => Processed [isFlagged] => NO )

    )
```

The above is response.So how i will get transationId value from this???

Comment: The first rule of SimpleXML is not to trust `print_r` (or `var_dump`, or anything like that). That is not an array, it is an object with special access mechanisms, as demonstrated in [the "basic usage" page of the manual](http://uk1.php.net/manual/en/simplexml.examples-basic.php).

Answer (score 2):

Use this. Because it just a attribute

`$ebs_status_response_xml['transactionId']`